# Avoiding "utils" package in project hierarchy

Tags: architecture, package, project

I hate the fact that the source code of my project has a holdall package named "utils". It doesn't make sense to me since I always end up with `Timer`, `VarInt`, `Singleton`, `Base64`, `Logger` classes which are not related to each other at all.

The fact that many large projects such as Java have such hierarchy could mean that there's no clean solution, but it might also be a backward compatibility issue. **What's the best practice?**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. In my last project I put those utils inside individuals packages, so as the project progressed I got other related classes, so, in this project (for Financial sector).

Cheers